# Remove timestamp from filename

Tags: rename, ms-dos, batch-rename

I need to rename files generated automatically, truncating a timestamp at the end.

Files are named "abcd_efgh_jklm_21.04.2015.csv", with the numbers being today's date in german culture spelling and the "abcd"-parts one or more plain text parts.
German culture uses . to separate the date parts, and that makes creating the rename instruction a problem (I think).
Target name should be "abcd_efgh_jklm.csv" - remove last underscore and everything following it.

A real life example for a name could be

```
CompanyA_Sales_Forecast_ThirdRevision_21.04.2015.csv
```

Here we have four word-parts, and the date part which should be zapped out. Result would be:

```
CompanyA_Sales_Forecast_ThirdRevision.csv
```

I read
[How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards)
and think I understood it mostly, but I cannot get it to work.
Best I got is

```
ren *.csv *_.csv
```

creating "abcd_efgh_jklm_.csv".
This is close, but I need to get the last underscore removed also. I cannot figure that out.

Any advicde?

Comment: [relavent](http://superuser.com/questions/236820/how-do-i-remove-the-same-part-of-a-file-name-for-many-files-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

Command:

```
ren *.csv ????_????_????.csv
```

Sample:

```
>dir /b
abcd_efgh_ijkl_18.04.2015.csv
klmn_opqr_stuv_21.04.2015.csv
mnop_qrst_uvwx_19.04.2015.csv
yzab_cdef_ghij_20.04.2015.csv

>ren *.csv ????_????_????.csv

>dir /b
abcd_efgh_ijkl.csv
klmn_opqr_stuv.csv
mnop_qrst_uvwx.csv
yzab_cdef_ghij.csv
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, no, this does not help. The bits abcd_efgh are placeholders for real-life company names and objects. They are not 4 letters long and also more or less than 3 groups.

Comment: Oh well, that was not mentioned in the OP. Please update your question accordingly.