# Remove extra period in multiple file names

Tags: mp3, batch-rename

So I was looking into ways to do this like this post

[How do I remove the same part of a file name for many files in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/236820/how-do-i-remove-the-same-part-of-a-file-name-for-many-files-in-windows-7)

Because I wanted to change all the song files on my phone into mp3s. I used this program to do that to the 400 something songs. I wanted to remove some...

http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php

I accidentally changed the file extension to ".mp3" and not "mp3" so now all my files are called "(insertsongtitle)..mp3" and not "(insertsongtitle).mp3". How could I remove this preferably with a batch file?

Comment: Why don't you use BRU itself to do that? It's a powerful mass renaming utility that can easily do what you want.

Comment: or perl like so :    perl -npe s/..\/./g /somepathtofiles/songs.mp3

Comment: A person who knows how to use Perl wouldn't ask a question like this one.

Comment: Sorry I am not very knowledgeable at this stuff...

Comment: Simply use BRU. Replace (**Repl** in the app) a single dot/period with nothing/blank/empty string. When you select the files you'll be able to see the Preview in the New Name column so you can be sure of getting the result you want before pressing Rename.

Answer (score 0):

From the directory with your files, go into Powershell at the command prompt (type `powershell`) and try something like this:

`dir | Rename-Item -newname { $_.name -replace "..mp3", ".mp3" }`

Source:
http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/