# Remove variable string in all filenames at first occurrence of hyphen in powershell

Tags: command-line, powershell

How can I Remove variable string in all filenames until first occurrence of the hyphen in PowerShell?

I have a list of files in the same folder like:

```
picture_1_2017-01-02_abc.jpg
picture_10_2017-01-03_dfc.jpg
picture_111_2017-01-04_sdfc.jpg
picture_20_2017-01-05_gh.jpg
picture_354_2017-01-06_asfd.jpg
...
```

I'd like to replace everything until first "**hyphen**" by "**2017**". 
For example, to replace "**picture_10_2017**" by "**2017**" and leave the rest of the name as is to receive the next list of files:

```
2017-01-02_abc.jpg
2017-01-03_dfc.jpg
2017-01-04_sdfc.jpg
2017-01-05_gh.jpg
2017-01-06_asfd.jpg
```

How can I do that in windows by PowerShell or any other tool?

Comment: Is this the same as removing the `picture_*_` prefix in your case, or are there variations?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. The text remains the same , only the number _*_ varies. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this earlier question](https://superuser.com/questions/236820/how-do-i-remove-the-same-part-of-a-file-name-for-many-files-in-windows-7), the overall structure for mass-renaming files is:

```
Get-ChildItem <glob> | foreach { Rename-Item $_ <newname> }
```

Each item has its original name stored in `$_.Name`, and when the regular fixed-string .Replace() method is not enough, use regular expressions.

Within PowerShell, you can access regex-based Replace() in two ways:

- `[regex]::Replace($str, $regex, $replacement)`
- `$str -replace $regex, $replacement`

**To just remove the prefix**

The regex `^picture_\d+_` will match the unwanted prefix; replace it with nothing.

After combining the two:

```
Get-ChildItem *.jpg | % { Rename-Item $_ ([regex]::Replace($_.Name, "^picture_\d+_", "")) }

Get-ChildItem *.jpg | % { Rename-Item $_ ($_.Name -replace "^picture_\d+_", "") }
```

Alternatively, to match the question, `^[^-]*-` will match everything up to (and including) the first dash; replace it with `"2017-"` (assuming all files are from the same year – otherwise you might accidentally lose information).

**To replace with part of the original**

You can match part of the original text using `( )` and use it as the replacement using `$1` ($2, $3...) This will give the same final result in your case, but more closely matches what you originally asked.

For example, regex `"^picture_\d+_(\d+)-"` and replacement `'$1-'` (must be single-quoted).