Windows Batch Script: how to recursively go through all files except certain file types and folders?
I'm trying to do a replace string operation on all files except those in .git folder and all pycache directories which can appear nested in any nested directory. I'm executing the script in the root directory that contains a .git folder.
for /r /d %%F in (*) do (
    echo Checking: %%F
    if not "%%~xF"==".sh" if not "%%~xF"==".png" if not "%%~xF"==".bat" if not "%%~dpF"=="__pycache__\" if not "%%~dpF"==".git\" (
        echo Found file: %%F
        findstr /C:"{{ADDON_NAME_PACKAGE}} {{ADDON_NAME}} {{ADDON_NAME_FULL}}" "%%F" >nul 2>&1
        if not errorlevel 1 (
            echo %%F
            set "file=%%F"
            setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
            set "cmd=sed -i -e ""s/%replace_package%/%package_name%/g"" -e ""s/%replace_addon_name%/%addon_short_name%/g"" -e ""s/%replace_addon_name_full%/%addon_full_name%/g"" ""!file!""
            endlocal & !cmd!
            echo Replaced placeholders in !file!
        )
    )
)

But I am stuck in the if condition of this loop which still prints out all files in the .git folder even though it is excluded using if not "%%~dpF"==".git\". Why? I can't find any solution to this, not even chat gpt can tell me. How is that even possible that the AI doesn't know this? Also if not "%%~dpF"=="%CD%\.git\" does not work.
for /r /d %%F in (*) do (
    echo Checking: %%F
    if not "%%~xF"==".sh" if not "%%~xF"==".png" if not "%%~xF"==".bat" if not "%%~dpF"=="__pycache__\" if not "%%~dpF"==".git\" (
        echo Found file: %%F

which still prints out the files in the .git folder and __pycache__ folders. This is so easy to achieve using Unix/Linux
replace_package="{{ADDON_NAME_PACKAGE}}"
replace_addon_name="{{ADDON_NAME}}"
replace_addon_name_full="{{ADDON_NAME_FULL}}"

perform_replacements() {
    local file="$1"
    local package_name="$2"
    local addon_short_name="$3"
    local addon_full_name="$4"

    sed -i "s/${replace_package}/${package_name}/g; s/${replace_addon_name}/${addon_short_name}/g; s/${replace_addon_name_full}/${addon_full_name}/g" "$file"
}

find . \( -name .git -o -name __pycache__ \) -prune -o \( -type f -not -name "*.sh" -not -name "*.png" \) -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    perform_replacements "$file" "$package_name" "$addon_short_name" "$addon_full_name"
    echo "Replaced placeholders in $file"
done

So I don't understand why is it so complicated on windows .bat files to do the same? What gives?

why not use Powershell which has more features than batch?

i just have a .bat file which i want the user to be able to double click and execute. what kind of file extension would i use for the powershell one? im a linux/unix guy not so much knowledge of windows. but even with cmd that should be an easy task. but why is it so complicated? but still curious if this is even possible with simple .bat file

Also possible in batch. However, it is easier in PowerShell in some jobs, including your task

PS is going to be a more capable scripting system on Windows. You could probably do a find and replace using a one-liner, but that may be more complex. Instead, like you've done with your bash script, you'll define the place your looking in, the things you want to avoid, and then you'll probably run "get-childitem", check each result against the exception list, and rename them.

A bit of a comment too: For someone well verse in batch, the above is simple to do in batch. For someone experienced in PS, it is a simple task in PS. For someone, like you, comfortable in Linux and Bash, it's easy in Bash. It's not a really complicated process: just using tools you're not so familiar with is the hard part.

Just did some looking and found that Get-ChildItem has an -Exclude argument, which makes this even simpler. You can filter the returned results right "find file" operation without needing additional sections. Then this question seems to be along the lines of what you're looking for: https://superuser.com/questions/1401772/remove-variable-string-in-all-filenames-at-first-occurrence-of-hyphen-in-powersh/1401853#1401853

@music2myear I think the OP was puzzled because why would chat gpt not be able to do such a trivial thing. so it seems to be very complicated task even for someone well versed in batch?

Write it in Python! (Saying this because reference to pycache directories suggests that Python is installed already).

This is not full answer. Only an example using PowerShell.
Save it to a file with extension .ps1. Ex: test.ps1, and place it in your working directory. To Execute, Right Click > Run with PowerShell.

Official Format

$WL1 = @('.bat', '.png', '.sh', '.ps1')
$WL2 = @('.git', '__pycache__')
if ($PWD.Path -ne $PSScriptRoot) {Push-Location -Path $PSScriptRoot}
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where {$_.Name -notin $WL2 -and $_.Extension -notin $WL1} |
ForEach-Object {$_.Name}
pause 

This will displays all files and directories except in filter $WL1 $WL2
You  can add a file or folder to be excluded  by its extension in $WL1, and by its name in $WL2.

Short Format

$WL1='.bat','.png','.sh','.ps1'
$WL2='.git','__pycache__'
Pushd $PSScriptRoot
GCI -R|? Name -notin $WL2|? Extension -notin $WL1|% Name
pause 

To Check All available filters, you can type Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Get-Member or GCI -R|GM in PowerShell Console in the directory.

thank you. you're right i will stick with powershell from now on :)

It's good to learn both.
The advantage of CMD is that it is light and fast because it doesn't have many features.
PowerShell is a development of CMD which is certainly more sophisticated and feature-rich.
For simple tasks, using CMD is the best choice because it loads faster. But for complex tasks, using CMD is a bad idea.

And in a corporate environment, BAT is more likely to be allowed than PS

@MikeB Certainly not my experience. Large swaths of Windows administration these days is done via PowerShell, so there's definitely an escape hatch. There can be certain security features activated, but PowerShell plays way nicer with those than cmd, so chances are if you're in a locked down environment by any even semi-competent administration that it'll be easier to create a signed PowerShell script and run that than get a random cmd script working.

While PowerShell scripts are vastly easier to write and read than your average batch script, they lack one thing: It's quite hard for your average user to execute them, since you can't just double click them.
There are easy solutions though, with the two most common ones being:
The easy one
Write your PowerShell script as normal. Then create a cmd script in which you put powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NoLogo -File "%~dp0\MyPowerShellFile.ps1. Now you can give your users both files and they can just double click the bat file as they're used to and it'll execute the powershell script.
This gets you the easy for users (and yourself) to use batch file, while getting all the power of PowerShell. The downside is you now have two files, which brings us to:
One file only
Similar to the previous one, but instead of calling a separate file, you can also integrate your whole script in the batch file and avoid the need for two files.
You can do this by using the -EncodedCommand parameter to pass a base64 encoded string to PowerShell which will contain your whole script.
A simple PowerShell function (have fun writing the equivalent code in cmd..) that takes any PS1 file and creates a bat file is the following:
function Convert-PowerShellToBatch
{
    param
    (        
       [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]
        [Alias("FullName")]
        $Path
    )
 
    process
    {
        $encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((Get-Content -Path $Path -Raw -Encoding UTF8)))
        $newPath = [Io.Path]::ChangeExtension($Path, ".bat")
        "@echo off`npowershell.exe -NoExit -encodedCommand $encoded" | Set-Content -Path $newPath -Encoding Ascii
    }
}

Source because I don't have my script collection at hand - but looks right.

If pwsh installed, possible to double click ps1 file using it after set it as default app for ps1 file
